# Pandas analogue to SQL MINUS / EXCEPT operator, using multiple columns

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe

I'm looking for the fastest and idiomatic analog to [SQL MINUS (AKA EXCEPT) operator](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/minus.php).

Here is what I mean - given two Pandas DataFrames as follows:

```
In [77]: d1
Out[77]:
   a  b  c
0  0  0  1
1  0  1  2
2  1  0  3
3  1  1  4
4  0  0  5
5  1  1  6
6  2  2  7

In [78]: d2
Out[78]:
   a  b   c
0  1  1  10
1  0  0  11
2  1  1  12
```

How to find a result of `d1 MINUS d2` taking into account only columns `"a"` and `"b"` in order to get the following result:

```
In [62]: res
Out[62]:
   a  b  c
1  0  1  2
2  1  0  3
6  2  2  7
```

MVCE:

```
d1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2], 
    'b': [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2], 
    'c': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
})

d2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [1, 0, 1], 
    'b': [1, 0, 1], 
    'c': [10, 11, 12]
})
```

---

What have I tried:

```
In [65]: tmp1 = d1.reset_index().set_index(["a", "b"])

In [66]: idx = tmp1.index.difference(d2.set_index(["a","b"]).index)

In [67]: res = d1.loc[tmp1.loc[idx, "index"]]

In [68]: res
Out[68]:
   a  b  c
1  0  1  2
2  1  0  3
6  2  2  7
```

it gives me correct results, but I have a feeling that there must be a more idiomatic and nicer / cleaner way to achieve that.

PS [DataFrame.isin()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) method won't help in this case as it'll produce a wrong result set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) here and pass it the argument to drop *all duplicates* with `keep=False`:

```
pd.concat([d1, d2]).drop_duplicates(['a', 'b'], keep=False)

   a  b  c
1  0  1  2
2  1  0  3
6  2  2  7
```

**Edit after comment by OP**

If you want to make sure that unique rows in `df2` arnt taken into account, we can duplicate that `df`:

```
pd.concat([d1, pd.concat([d2]*2)]).drop_duplicates(['a', 'b'], keep=False)

   a  b  c
1  0  1  2
2  1  0  3
6  2  2  7
```

Comment: Thank you for you solution! Unfortunately it will not work correctly if `d2` will have rows that are not in `d1` (For example try to add: `d2.loc[3] = [10] * 3` - your solution would return a row `[10, 10, 10]` - which should not be there). I'm sorry that i didn't think of it when creating test data sets...

Comment: I see, didn't take that into account. No problem.

Comment: Had to take a look at this question again, I edited my answer with a solution that should work. Wondering how it holds in terms of speed @MaxU

Comment: Nice, glad I could help. Btw your answers helped me a lot, so glad I can do tiny bit back :) @MaxU

Answer (score 6):

### Execution time comparison for larger data sets:

```
In [100]: df1 = pd.concat([d1] * 10**5, ignore_index=True)

In [101]: df2 = pd.concat([d2] * 10**5, ignore_index=True)

In [102]: df1.shape
Out[102]: (700000, 3)

In [103]: df2.shape
Out[103]: (300000, 3)
```

## `pd.concat().drop_duplicates()` approach:

```
In [10]: %%timeit
    ...: res = pd.concat([d1, pd.concat([d2]*2)]).drop_duplicates(['a', 'b'], keep=False)
    ...:
    ...:
2.59 ms ± 129 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

## multi-index NOT IS IN approach:

```
In [11]: %%timeit
    ...: res = df1[~df1.set_index(["a", "b"]).index.isin(df2.set_index(["a","b"]).index)]
    ...:
    ...:
484 ms ± 18.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

## multi-index difference approach:

```
In [12]: %%timeit
    ...: tmp1 = df1.reset_index().set_index(["a", "b"])
    ...: idx = tmp1.index.difference(df2.set_index(["a","b"]).index)
    ...: res = df1.loc[tmp1.loc[idx, "index"]]
    ...:
    ...:
1.04 s ± 20.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

## `merge(how="outer")` approach - gives me a `MemoryError`:

```
In [106]: %%timeit
     ...: res =  (df1.reset_index()
     ...:         .merge(df2, on=['a','b'], indicator=True, how='outer', suffixes=('','_'))
     ...:         .query('_merge == "left_only"')
     ...:         .set_index('index')
     ...:         .rename_axis(None)
     ...:         .reindex(df1.columns, axis=1))
     ...:
     ...:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
```

## compare concatenated strings approach:

```
In [13]: %%timeit
    ...: res = df1[~df1[['a','b']].astype(str).sum(axis=1).isin(df2[['a','b']].astype(str).sum(axis=1))]
    ...:
    ...:
2.05 s ± 65.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution with `merge` and `indicator=True`:

```
df = (d1.reset_index()
        .merge(d2, on=['a','b'], indicator=True, how='outer', suffixes=('','_'))
        .query('_merge == "left_only"')
        .set_index('index')
        .rename_axis(None)
        .reindex(d1.columns, axis=1))
print (df)
   a  b  c
1  0  1  2
2  1  0  3
6  2  2  7
```

Solution with `isin`:

```
df = d1[~d1.set_index(["a", "b"]).index.isin(d2.set_index(["a","b"]).index)]
print (df)
   a  b  c
1  0  1  2
2  1  0  3
6  2  2  7
```

Comment: I wanted to measure the execution speed for our solutions on a larger data sets (`df1 = pd.concat([d1] * 10**4, ignore_index=True); df2 = pd.concat([d2] * 10**4, ignore_index=True);`), but I'm constantly getting `MemoryError` after trying to use `merge()` - i think it's because of duplicates. Unfortunately in my real task i will have lots of duplicates as well...

Comment: You get the memory error because of `outer` join which will reproduce a `m x n` dataframe. So the amount of rows will explode depending on the matches it finds in column a & b @MaxU

Answer (score 3):

I am thinking a little bit like excel here:

```
d1[~d1[['a','b']].astype(str).sum(axis=1).isin(d2[['a','b']].astype(str).sum(axis=1))]
```

---

```
   a  b  c
1  0  1  2
2  1  0  3
6  2  2  7
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution! By the way I have already upvoted it :) I had this idea as well but i thought it might interfere with values and might not always work well...

Answer (score -1):

I had similar question, I tried your idea

```
(
In [65]: tmp1 = d1.reset_index().set_index(["a", "b"])

In [66]: idx = tmp1.index.difference(d2.set_index(["a","b"]).index)

In [67]: res = d1.loc[tmp1.loc[idx, "index"]]

)
```

for test and it **works**.

However, I use the way in my sqlite, tow databases that have the same Structure,that means its tables and tables' columns are the same, and it occurred some mistakes, it shows that this two df seems don't have the same shap.

if u r happy to give me a hand and want more details, we can have a further conversation thanks a lot