# Pandas: delete or change specific rows according to multiple columns values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary between tuples to list of values, for example:

```
{
    ('book1', 'US'): [1, 5],
    ('book2', 'CA'): [3]
}
```

The tuple represents columns values in pandas `DataFrame` (there might be other columns as well) and the list represents values in a single column in the same dataframe.
Let's say my dataframe looks something like this:

```
    book country  value
0  book1      US      1
1  book1      US      9
2  book1      US      5
3  book2      MX      7
4  book2      CA      3
5  book1      CA      1
```

I would like to either delete the rows that the `dict` above represents or change the value of those rows to 0.
So the result will be either:

```
    book country  value
0  book1      US      0
1  book1      US      9
2  book1      US      0
3  book2      MX      7
4  book2      CA      0
5  book1      CA      1
```

Or:

```
    book country  value
0  book1      US      9
1  book2      MX      7
2  book1      CA      1
```

What is the best approach for doing this?
I want to do this on a pretty large dataframe and it should be as efficient as possible.

My idea was doing something like this, but it doesn't seem very efficient (due to the multiple `loc`) and I get duplicates rows instead of removing the rows. (I don't want to use `drop_duplicates` as there might be duplicates at first place that I don't want to drop)

```
data_frame.set_index(['book', 'country'], inplace=True)
for key, values in rows_to_remove.iteritems():
    data_frame.loc[key] = data_frame.loc[key][~data_frame.loc[key]['value'].isin(values)]
data_frame.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create list of tuples and check membership by [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
d = {
    ('book1', 'US'): [1, 5],
    ('book2', 'CA'): [3]
}

tups = [k + (x, ) for k, v in d.items() for x in v]

df = df[~df.set_index(['book','country','value']).index.isin(tups)]
print (df)
    book country  value
1  book1      US      9
3  book2      MX      7
5  book1      CA      1
```

For set `0` by condition use `loc`:

```
df.loc[df.set_index(['book','country','value']).index.isin(tups), 'value'] = 0
print (df)
    book country  value
0  book1      US      0
1  book1      US      9
2  book1      US      0
3  book2      MX      7
4  book2      CA      0
5  book1      CA      1
```

Another solution:

```
tups = [k + (x, ) for k, v in d.items() for x in v]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(tups, columns=['book','country','value'])

df2 = pd.concat([df, df1, df1], ignore_index=True)
df = df2[~df2.duplicated(keep=False)]
print (df)
    book country  value
1  book1      US      9
3  book2      MX      7
5  book1      CA      1
```

Comment: Nice! Is `set_index` expensive? What if I have multiple metric dimensions and I want to run this multiple times on every metric? (i.e. if I have `value1`, `value2`, `value3`).
I didn't add it to the question for simplicity but do you think the approach you suggested is still the best way in this case?  
Thanks!

Comment: @A.Sarid - I think no, there should be more expensive `isin`.

Comment: @A.Sarid - Added another solution, can you check it?

Comment: Thanks! The solutions works of course. Can you explain what's the difference? Is it more efficient?   
I am still trying to figure out if it's the most efficient way of doing it assuming I have multiple value columns and I need to run this logic on every one of them.

Comment: @A.Sarid - yes, it is more eficient. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56237223/2901002)

Comment: Actually, the original `df` might have duplicates, so the new solution you suggested is not good for me. But the other ones work good, not very efficient, but works good.