# Delete values of all rows of a dataset from another another dataset

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, machine-learning

For an example, I have following 2 datasets:

df1 =

[image]

df2 =

[image]

here the values of df2 is already in df1 (row 1, 4 and 5).
Now I have to make another dataset df3 where only row 2 and 3 will exist.

df3 =

[image]

I studied lots of thing about splitting dataset but as a new learner I can't find the exact solution of it. 
If I said anything wrong please feel free to correct me. I will be very glad if anyone can help me regarding this issue. Thanks.

Comment: sorry. I am correcting it.

Comment: also can you check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56235226/pandas-analogue-to-sql-minus-except-operator-using-multiple-columns/56235551#56235551 does it help?

Comment: yes. I got my answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem, as it has been answered before, closed as dupe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get DF's difference use drop_duplicate method as below

```
pd.concat([df1,df2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```